# how to dismiss the alert programatically using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Hi I am new for developing ios application.
I have used some cocopods framework for doing the alert view. 
I have used alert view following mentioned [sweetAlert](https://github.com/codestergit/SweetAlert-iOS). 
In that I have tried to dismiss the alert programmatically with out press the tab button in alert.
Please any one help for fix the problem.

Comment: You can use timer:NSTimer- that can hide your Alertview after a preferred time

Comment: I have tried its not working.

Comment: Please add the code snippet, Basically what you are trying.

Comment: Actually I have able to use above mentioned SweetAlert frameWork. In that Its have information with button. but I need only text after that it has close programmatically. I have done hide that button. but it has not close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `pressed(sender: UIButton!)` method in SweetAlert class.

```
@IBAction func aBasicMessageAlert(sender: AnyObject) {
    let sweetAlert = SweetAlert().showAlert("Here's a message!")

    close(sweetAlert, after: 2.0)
}


func close(alert: SweetAlert, after seconds: Double) {
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(seconds,
                                           target: self,
                                           selector: #selector(closeAlert),
                                           userInfo: ["alert": alert],
                                           repeats: true)
}

func closeAlert(timer: NSTimer) {
    let alert = timer.userInfo!["alert"] as! SweetAlert

    let dummyCloseButton = UIButton()
    dummyCloseButton.tag = 0
    alert.pressed(dummyCloseButton)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can dismiss the alert by calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated` method on alertController object.

```
alertControllerObject?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
yourAlerView.dismiss(withClickedButtonIndex: 0, animated: true)
```

when you handle the return key.
ButtonIndex is index of button you want to click by default to hide alert.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this method in SweetAlert, and call it.

```
func closeAlert(){


        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.alpha = 0.0
        }) { (Bool) -> Void in
            self.view.removeFromSuperview()
            self.cleanUpAlert()

            //Releasing strong refrence of itself.
            self.strongSelf = nil
        }
    }
```

Implement alert like this

```
let  alert = SweetAlert() // take this as global
func showAlert(){

        alert.showAlert(title as String, subTitle: msg as String, style: style, buttonTitle:buttonOtherTitle as String, buttonColor:UIColor.redColor() , otherButtonTitle:  buttonOkTitle as String, otherButtonColor: colors.KBlueTextColor!) { (isOtherButton) -> Void in
            if isOtherButton
            {
                completionHandler(false)
            }
            else
            {
                completionHandler(true)
            }
        }
    }
func CloseAlert(){


         alert.closeAlert()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

**When you call Alert Method Also Called this, Inside the alert Method**

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "hideAlert:", userInfo: userInfo, repeats: true) //repeats: false
```

**Called This outside the Alert Method**

```
 func hideAlert(){
        isOtherButton == true// isOtherButton getting from your SweetAlert Demo
    }
```